# How to run process with no window

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, process, flutter-desktop

```
Process.run(
  'adb',
  ['devices],
  runInShell: true,
);
```

When I run the app in android studio, no black window,
But when I double-click ***.exe to run the app, it will see the black window

Comment: This is how Windows runs console-mode applications.

Comment: @jamesdlin Flutter desktop applications aren't console-mode. The issue is with how Dart spawns processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a Dart bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39945).

As [described in the comments there](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39945#issuecomment-870428151), you can work around it for now by creating your own console at launch and hiding it:

```
if (!::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) && ::IsDebuggerPresent()) {
  CreateAndAttachConsole();
} else {
  AllocConsole();
  ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}
```